# Add product accessories programatically in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have added an extension of Product i.e. Accessories.
Now, I have products and their accessories ids in a CSV file. I searched through Google, but couldn't found that how to add product accessories in Magento through PHP.
I need some assistance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the api. Just change the word related to 'accessories'. The module extends the product link stuff like up-sells, cross sells, related products etc and you should be able to create a script that reads your file, and use the API to setup the links. If you don't want to use the API (I would try that first if it were me), you can create a script and do something like the following;

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$linkProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($linked_product_id);

$xsLinkData[$linkProduct->getId()] = array('position' => 0);
$product->setAccessoriesLinkData($xsLinkData)->save();
```

The class 'Anais_Accessories_Model_Observer' shows how the module handles the linked accessories when you save a product.

Comment: This code successfully added accessories to the product. I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Product Links API functions to achieve this. I presume you want to setup the cross sell products (accessories) against each product? If so, you can create a php script which uses the API in magento to add the accessories as cross sells to the normal product. See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product_link for the documentation.

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

// Assign related product
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_link.assign', array('related', 'Sku', 'Sku2', array('position'=>0, 'qty'=>56)));
```

Comment: No, I have added an extension in Product - i.e. Accessories.
Now, I want to know that how can I add these accessories of product through PHP.

Comment: What extension or is a custom one? If a custom module you may need to create new models via PHP and assign the product they are for. Your question does not make it easy to understand exactly what you have done & tried I'm afraid.

Comment: I have added the accessories extension. Here's the link :
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-accessories.html

Comment: You're not asking a specific programming question.  What you're asking for is a step-by-step of how to do Magento customization.  Hire a developer.